# Can't create login with default database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

While creating login with default database I'm getting error:

> The database 'TradeRemoteManagement' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.

It happens only with one specific database, creating login with any other database except this one is successful. Creating via SSMS also raises the same error. Why does it happen?

[image]

UPDATE: Corresponding record in sys.databases

> name  :   TradeRemoteManagement
>
> database_id   :   25
>
> source_database_id    :   NULL
>
> owner_sid :   0x0105000000000005150000008BAB9AFF5CA20F28849F020875070000
>
> create_date   :   10/02/2016 23:50
>
> compatibility_level   :   120
>
> collation_name    :   Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
>
> user_access   :   0
>
> user_access_desc  :   MULTI_USER
>
> is_read_only  :   0
>
> is_auto_close_on  :   0
>
> is_auto_shrink_on :   0
>
> state :   0
>
> state_desc    :   ONLINE
>
> is_in_standby :   0
>
> is_cleanly_shutdown   :   0
>
> is_supplemental_logging_enabled   :   0
>
> snapshot_isolation_state  :   0
>
> snapshot_isolation_state_desc :   OFF
>
> is_read_committed_snapshot_on :   0
>
> recovery_model    :   1
>
> recovery_model_desc   :   FULL
>
> page_verify_option    :   2
>
> page_verify_option_desc   :   CHECKSUM
>
> is_auto_create_stats_on   :   1
>
> is_auto_create_stats_incremental_on   :   0
>
> is_auto_update_stats_on   :   1
>
> is_auto_update_stats_async_on :   0
>
> is_ansi_null_default_on   :   0
>
> is_ansi_nulls_on  :   0
>
> is_ansi_padding_on    :   0
>
> is_ansi_warnings_on   :   0
>
> is_arithabort_on  :   0
>
> is_concat_null_yields_null_on :   0
>
> is_numeric_roundabort_on  :   0
>
> is_quoted_identifier_on   :   0
>
> is_recursive_triggers_on  :   0
>
> is_cursor_close_on_commit_on  :   0
>
> is_local_cursor_default   :   0
>
> is_fulltext_enabled   :   1
>
> is_trustworthy_on :   0
>
> is_db_chaining_on :   0
>
> is_parameterization_forced    :   0
>
> is_master_key_encrypted_by_server :   0
>
> is_query_store_on :   0
>
> is_published  :   0
>
> is_subscribed :   0
>
> is_merge_published    :   0
>
> is_distributor    :   0
>
> is_sync_with_backup   :   0
>
> service_broker_guid   :   D6DD49C2-0E57-44D7-A531-6003739292AD
>
> is_broker_enabled :   0
>
> log_reuse_wait    :   7
>
> log_reuse_wait_desc   :   DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION
>
> is_date_correlation_on    :   0
>
> is_cdc_enabled    :   0
>
> is_encrypted  :   0
>
> is_honor_broker_priority_on   :   0
>
> replica_id    :   NULL
>
> group_database_id :   NULL
>
> resource_pool_id  :   NULL
>
> default_language_lcid :   NULL
>
> default_language_name :   NULL
>
> default_fulltext_language_lcid    :   NULL
>
> default_fulltext_language_name    :   NULL
>
> is_nested_triggers_on :   NULL
>
> is_transform_noise_words_on   :   NULL
>
> two_digit_year_cutoff :   NULL
>
> containment   :   0
>
> containment_desc  :   NONE
>
> target_recovery_time_in_seconds   :   0
>
> delayed_durability    :   0
>
> delayed_durability_desc   :   DISABLED
>
> is_memory_optimized_elevate_to_snapshot_on    :   0

Comment: Just for the sake of asking the obvious: Have you actually checked, if TradeRemoteManagement is listed inside `sys.databases`?

Comment: Yes, of course. It was the first what i have checked.

Comment: Also I have tried to detach-attach database, restore it from backup, even recreate it with different name.

Comment: Single User Mode? (your img link is blocked on my current network so I can only guess)

Comment: No, multi-user. Database is online

Comment: @Filburt I added the result of "select * from sys.databases" for this database

Comment: select len(yourdatabasenameinput),select len(db_name()) by changing database

Comment: @TheGameiswar 21, 21

Comment: Bug should bite all ,in most cases.can you try doing the same from UI

Comment: @TheGameiswar Yes, same error

Comment: could you try by executing create user statement from another window?

Comment: I have tried another window, another instance of SSMS, another computer with SSMS and the result was the same. The issue is in SQL instance because on another sql server with this database everything works fine.